# Is it possible to remotely make a seat reservation for Serbian trains?

Tags: trains, serbia

Is it possible to make a seat reservation for train in Serbia remotely, via the Internet or phone?

Trains can be overfilled in touring season and having a seat is a great thing when traveling through the country during the night (and not having one would be very exhausting, in case you can't sleep in standing position).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is. You can make reservations for domestic trains and for trains to Montenegro via e-mail or telephone. You find the contact details on the [Serbian Railways site](http://www.serbianrailways.com/active/en/home/glavna_navigacija/putnicki_saobracaj/rezervisanje_mesta.html).